# Redefine flink config for particular run

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there any way to redefine certain config properties from `conf/flink-conf.yaml` for particular job run? E.g. security keytab. Something like:

```
bin/flink run --conf "security.kerberos.login.keytab=/path" ...
```

It would be useful to have different authentication for different pipelines.